Can I use Bicep to create a token credential for a container registry?
I am trying to create a container registry through Azure Bicep, and as part of that, also create access tokens inside of it.
My .bicep file includes this section:
param tokenExpiry string = dateTimeAdd(utcNow(), 'P30D')

resource MyToken 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/tokens@2022-12-01' = {
  parent: containerRegistry
  name: 'MyToken'
  properties: {
    status: 'enabled'
    scopeMapId: resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/scopeMaps', containerRegistry.name, '_repositories_pull')
    credentials: {
      passwords: [
        {
           name: 'password1'
           expiry: tokenExpiry
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}

However, upon running the deployment, this fails:
[{"code":"PasswordCannotBeAdded","message":"New passwords can be added only through 'generateCredentials'.
I've tried adding a value property to the password (like I would for a key vault), but that also fails: {"code":"PasswordPropertiesImmutable","message":"Password properties cannot be changed. To retain the password, please provide an empty value for a password. To add a new password please use 'generateCredentials'.
I'm not seeing a way to call generateCredentials from within a bicep script, and the only search result was a mention of the New-AzContainerRegistryToken PowerShell cmdlet.
Am I maybe misusing bicep here? I'd like to ensure that there's only ever a specific set of Access Tokens in the registry, and if I want to refresh them, I'd just run bicep again.
Can I do this, or would I have to create the token without any credentials and then have to create the passwords separately through the REST API?

Did you get this working? Im trying to do the same thing in arm.

@devhl No, it doesn't seem to be supported in bicep, I had to write a separate script that uses az acr token credential generate  --query "passwords[].value" -o tsv to generate/rotate the token and read it back from the output.

You can add tokens with a name only. This token name can be likened to a username.
You can't directly modify the credentials of a token. You can only use the generateCredentials API or action.
The API accepts a tokenId, expiry, and optionally a name. The name here indicates which of the two passwords to generate, and must be either "password1" or "password2". If name is not specified, both password1 and password2 are (re)generated.
There is no way to specify your own passwords. When generateCredentials is called successfully, the response will contain the two random passwords generated internally.
I can't guarantee this will work, but you could maybe try something like this:
param tokenExpiry string = dateTimeAdd(utcNow(), 'P30D')

resource MyToken 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/tokens@2022-12-01' = {
  name: 'MyToken'
}

resource MyCreds 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/generateCredentials/action@2023-01-01-preview' = {
  name: 'MyCreds'
  tokenId: MyToken.id
  expiry: tokenExpiry
}

If this doesn't work, you'll need to call the API directly. If you've automated deployments, you could use Invoke-RestMethod or curl in a script. You'll need an access token to include in your request though.
API reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/registries/generate-credentials?view=rest-containerregistry-2023-01-01-preview&tabs=HTTP#security
